# Sorting sentences of text file by users input

Tags: python-3.x, file, sorting, input, sentence

My code is sorting the sentences of file based on a length of the sentences by their length and saving to a new file.

How can I alter my code so that if the user inputs any number at program start, we filter the lines based on that input.

Example: The user inputs `50` - the program will sort all sentences that have a greater length than 50 or if the user inputs `all` then the program will sort all lines as normal.

**My code:**

```
file = open("testing_for_tools.txt", "r")
lines_ = file.readlines()
#print(lines_)
user_input = input("enter")
if user_input is int:
    lines = sorted(lines_, key=len)
else:
    lines = sorted(lines_, key=len)
# lines.sort()
file_out = open('testing_for_tools_sorted.txt', 'w')
file_out.write(''.join(lines))  # Write a sequence of strings to a file
file_out.close()
file.close()
print(lines)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- input returns a string, always, if you want an integer or somesuch you need to parse it explicitely, you will never get an integer out of `input`.
- `is` is not a type-testing primitive in python, it's an *identity* primitive. It checks if the left and right are the same object and that's *it*.
- `filter` is what you're looking for here, or a *list comprehension*: if the user provided an input *and* that input is a valid integer, you want to filter the lines  to only those above the specified length. This is a separate step from sorting.

That aside,

- you should use `with` to manage files unless there are specific reasons that you shan't or can't
- files have a `writelines` method which should be more efficient than writing joined lines
- never *ever* open files in text mode without providing an encoding, otherwise Python asks the system for an encoding and it's easy for that system to be misconfigured or oddly configured leading to garbage inputs

```py
with open("testing_for_tools.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lines_ = file.readlines()

#print(lines_)
user_input = input("enter")
if user_input:
    try:
        limit = int(user_input.strip())
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        lines_ = (l for l in lines_ if len(l) >= limit)

lines = sorted(lines_, key=len)
with open('testing_for_tools_sorted.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
print(lines)
```

Comment: Your try\expect clause is a very bad coding example. It should _at least_ warn the user (and preferably let them retry).

Answer (score 1):

@Black Snow
I don't have anything else to answer if its working as expected.
This is a rather long answer:

```
idx_to_sort = [True if len(i)>int(user_input) else False for i in lines_]
idx_to_sort

lines_to_sort = []
for i in range(len(idx_to_sort)):
    if idx_to_sort[i]:
        lines_to_sort.append(lines_[i])

lines_to_sort

lines = sorted(lines_to_sort, key=len)
lines

counter=0
for i in range(len(idx_to_sort)):
    if idx_to_sort[i]:
        lines_[i] = lines[counter]
        counter += 1
lines_
```

The output would be different but not what you expected.